# Events won't trigger when working with API request

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to get the the submitted value in my form input using addEvent listener but  none of events work. Events only trigger when I comment my API request code block. Can you help figuring out this bug? Here is my code:

```
import Api from './api';
const apiConfig  = require ("../config.json");

// Dom queries
const searchForm = document.getElementById('search');
const submit = document.querySelector('button');

submit.addEventListener('click', e =>{
    console.log("hello");
});

searchForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("hello");
})


const updateUi = imageUrl => {
    let template = `<img src="${imageUrl}">`;
    document.body.innerHTML += template;
};


const getTrending =  new Api('http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/trending', {api_key: apiConfig.apiKey});
const data = getTrending.makeRequest();
data.then( data => {
    var responseData = data.data;
    responseData.forEach( gifdata => {
        const gifUrl = gifdata.images.original.url;
        updateUi(gifUrl);
    })}
).catch( err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: By "events not working" do you mean the console.log's are not logging out? Is the code inside of the events being fired when you click the button and/or submit the form?

Answer (score 0):

Finally! I found the mistake. I was replacing body's innerhtml with the api Data. Also the the input filled to which I added an event listener which was inside my body got replaced with the API data. So `no element === no event`. But weird think I found was if I am replacing my total inner html of my body after successful Api request then why input field was still visible?? This bug took me hours to figure out why I am facing this issue. Happy that I fixed it!